# python2.7 library not found while installing http-parser

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc, pip, ld

The error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7` shows up, when installing the `http-parser` package using `pip`.

`/opt/bitnami/python/include/python2.7` is present at that path.

There's a lot of debugging output, but the problem appears to be the missing library. If so, then how to fix it?

Full output:

```
$ pip install http-parser
Collecting http-parser
  Using cached http-parser-0.8.3.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: http-parser
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for http-parser ... error
  Complete output from command /opt/bitnami/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-PF6NIJ/http-parser/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmplt4SwWpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
  copying http_parser/pyparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
  copying http_parser/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
  copying http_parser/http.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
  copying http_parser/_socketio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
  copying http_parser/reader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
  copying http_parser/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
  running build_ext
  building 'http_parser.parser' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
  gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -fPIC -Iparser -I/opt/bitnami/python/include/python2.7 -c http_parser/http_parser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/http_parser.o
  gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -fPIC -Iparser -I/opt/bitnami/python/include/python2.7 -c http_parser/parser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/parser.o
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_header_field_cb’:
  http_parser/parser.c:1354:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 89; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:1354:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_header_value_cb’:
  http_parser/parser.c:1565:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 106; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:1565:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_headers_complete_cb’:
  http_parser/parser.c:1636:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 111; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:1636:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:1723:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
         __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 117; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
         ^
  http_parser/parser.c:1723:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:1796:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
         __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 123; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto debug2: channel 0: window 995591 sent adjust 52985
__pyx_L1_error;}
         ^
  http_parser/parser.c:1796:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_message_begin_cb’:
  http_parser/parser.c:1888:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 129; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:1888:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_body_cb’:
  http_parser/parser.c:1974:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 137; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:1974:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:2185:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
         __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 149; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
         ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2185:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_message_complete_cb’:
  http_parser/parser.c:2272:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 156; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2272:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_11http_parser_6parser_11_ParserData___init__’:
  http_parser/parser.c:2708:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 181; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2708:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:2720:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 183; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2720:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:2732:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 185; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2732:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:2744:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 186; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2744:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:2756:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 187; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2756:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:2768:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 188; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2768:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:2789:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 191; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:2789:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_11http_parser_6parser_10HttpParser_24get_wsgi_environ’:
  http_parser/parser.c:4430:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __Pyx_INCREF(((PyObject *)((PyObject*)(&PyString_Type))));
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_11http_parser_6parser_10HttpParser_26recv_body’:
  http_parser/parser.c:4617:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 336; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:4617:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_11http_parser_6parser_10HttpParser_28recv_body_into’:
  http_parser/parser.c:4827:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_3 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 349; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
  http_parser/parser.c:4827:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘initparser’:
  http_parser/parser.c:6034:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_5 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_5)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 173; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:6034:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:6039:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_5 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_5)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 173; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:6039:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:6074:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 205; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:6074:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  http_parser/parser.c:6079:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 205; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
     ^
  http_parser/parser.c:6079:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  gcc -pthread -shared -L/bitnami/nodejsstack-linux-x64/output/sqlite/lib -L/bitnami/nodejsstack-linux-x64/output/common/lib -L/opt/bitnami/common/lib -L/opt/bitnami/common/lib -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/http_parser.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/parser.o -L/bitnami/nodejsstack-linux-x64/output/python/lib -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/parser.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for http-parser
  Running setup.py clean for http-parser
Failed to build http-parser
Installing collected packages: http-parser
  Running setup.py install for http-parser ... error
    Complete output from command /opt/bitnami/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-PF6NIJ/http-parser/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9vcNyt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
    copying http_parser/pyparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
    copying http_parser/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
    copying http_parser/http.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
    copying http_parser/_socketio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
    copying http_parser/reader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
    copying http_parser/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
    running build_ext
    building 'http_parser.parser' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser
    gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -fPIC -Iparser -I/opt/bitnami/python/include/python2.7 -c http_parser/http_parser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/http_parser.o
    gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -fPIC -Iparser -I/opt/bitnami/python/include/python2.7 -c http_parser/parser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/parser.o
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_header_field_cb’:
    http_parser/parser.c:1354:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 89; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:1354:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_header_value_cb’:
    http_parser/parser.c:1565:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 106; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:1565:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_headers_complete_cb’:
    http_parser/parser.c:1636:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 111; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:1636:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:1723:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
           __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 117; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
           ^
    http_parser/parser.c:1723:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:1796:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
           __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 123; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
           ^
    http_parser/parser.c:1796:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_message_begin_cb’:
    http_parser/parser.c:1888:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 129; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:1888:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_body_cb’:
    http_parser/parser.c:1974:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 137; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:1974:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:2185:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
           __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 149; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
           ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2185:7: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_11http_parser_6parser_on_message_complete_cb’:
    http_parser/parser.c:2272:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 156; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2272:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_11http_parser_6parser_11_ParserData___init__’:
    http_parser/parser.c:2708:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 181; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2708:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:2720:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 183; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2720:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:2732:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 185; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2732:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:2744:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 186; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2744:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:2756:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 187; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2756:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:2768:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 188; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2768:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:2789:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 191; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:2789:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_11http_parser_6parser_10HttpParser_24get_wsgi_environ’:
    http_parser/parser.c:4430:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __Pyx_INCREF(((PyObject *)((PyObject*)(&PyString_Type))));
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_11http_parser_6parser_10HttpParser_26recv_body’:
    http_parser/parser.c:4617:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 336; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:4617:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_11http_parser_6parser_10HttpParser_28recv_body_into’:
    http_parser/parser.c:4827:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
         __pyx_t_3 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 349; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
         ^
    http_parser/parser.c:4827:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c: In function ‘initparser’:
    http_parser/parser.c:6034:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_5 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_5)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 173; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:6034:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:6039:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_5 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_5)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 173; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:6039:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:6074:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 205; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:6074:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    http_parser/parser.c:6079:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 205; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
       ^
    http_parser/parser.c:6079:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    gcc -pthread -shared -L/bitnami/nodejsstack-linux-x64/output/sqlite/lib -L/bitnami/nodejsstack-linux-x64/output/common/lib -L/opt/bitnami/common/lib -L/opt/bitnami/common/lib -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -I/opt/bitnami/common/include/ImageMagick -I/opt/bitnami/common/include build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/http_parser.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/parser.o -L/bitnami/nodejsstack-linux-x64/output/python/lib -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/http_parser/parser.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-PF6NIJ/http-parser/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9vcNyt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PF6NIJ/http-parser/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: I believe it's saying it can't find `libpython2.7.so`; does this file exist at that precise location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libpython2.7.so` exists in `/opt/bitnami/python/lib`.

`ldconfig -v` told me that the `ld` command is not looking there, so I created a symbolic link to it in `/lib` to make sure it gets found.